# Drop or alter a column that begins and ends with square bracket [ ]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column name "[UserUpdateTstmp]".
Want to rename and remove [] from start and end respectively but couldn't due to square bracket [].

I tried:

- To drop column:

`alter table InsReconTxn drop column [UserUpdateTstmp]`

> Error- Msg 4924, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN
> failed because column 'UserUpdateTstmp' does not exist in table
> 'InsReconTxn'.

- To rename column:

`exec sp_RENAME 'InsReconTxn.[UserUpdateTstmp]', 'UserUpdateTstmp', 'COLUMN'`

> Error - exec sp_RENAME 'InsReconTxn.[UserUpdateTstmp]',
> 'UserUpdateTstmp', 'COLUMN'

Help needed!

Comment: What error are you getting when using `EXEC SP_RENAME`?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy - "Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 264 [Batch Start Line 12]
Either the parameter @@objname is ambiguous or the claimed @@objtype (COLUMN) is wrong."

Comment: I kept one extra @ before objname just to post else its not allowing.

Comment: Not able to replicate. [Check this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8afad65f2403ad8d41b84564649cca28)

Comment: Updated the same fiddler with my query, plz check the last 3 query where I added square bracket in column name but unable to remove it. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=bbce4f1b83e667b54a18dcd6569a9f65

Comment: In the second case, you are adding one more Square bracket. so you have to use `EXEC Sp_RENAME 'InsReconTxn.[[UserUpdateTstmp]]]', 'UserUpdateTstmp','COLUMN'`. [Updated the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3f4936e4017f1bfd5b88438a2e313b7d)

Comment: Thanks alot @ArunPalanisamy. It worked.

Comment: you could have saved yourself an hour of discussion in the comments by just looking at the duplicate question